# Cache memory overflow in chrome

Tags: image, google-chrome, browser-cache

Reading img frames emitted by a streamer in the `HTML` *img* component's source attribute. Everything works fine the frames are updated but the **chrome browser** caches all the frames (I checked via task manager in chrome) so **cache memory keeps on increasing and results in the app crash**.

However in firefox and in opera the very same app does not cause cache pile-up and remains constant to one iteration of the app.

```
Headers-
Cache-control : no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0
```